# Simplifying value (order of magnitude reduction and display)

Tags: vb.net

Okay- I am not 100% sure this question doesn't exist, as there are many ways to word a problem. but I think it doesn't exist (you know how internet searches are) s0 please bear with me.

I am writing a short mini-game program, for a online class. It involves a digital "currency" and I have implemented a logarithmic "check" to tell the user if he/she has "x" amount of money with orders of magnitude. This is just the background. Not the problem.

In the program they have the following (in the main form class). It is in the timer section because the full program requires a constant update for any increase in the "money"

```
 Dim myFragments As Integer
    Dim FragmentExponent As Double
    Dim myExponent As Double
 FragmentExponent = myFragments
myFragments = 0 'insert whatever value to test 

Private Sub tmrUnknown_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUnknown.Tick

lblMoney.Text = myFragments
        myExponent = Math.Log10(FragmentExponent)
        If myExponent < 3 Then lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = " "
        If myExponent >= 3 And myExponent <= 5 Then lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Thousand"
        If myExponent >= 6 And myExponent <= 8 Then lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Million"
        If myExponent >= 9 And myExponent <= 11 Then lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Billion"
        If myExponent >= 12 And myExponent <= 14 Then lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Trillion"
        If myExponent >= 15 And myExponent <= 17 Then lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Quadrillion"
end sub


                                     ...
```

You get the idea.

But when I display the myMoney value to a label, I still have the original unmodified text, as well as the order of magnitude denotation. (and I know the above code doesn't address the issue, it is a background aid in understanding).

**Question: How would I modify the data value to display only the first three significant digits?**

It may just be me, but I am having a problem figuring out the math behind it.  (and creating new variables/ "rerouting" how the program runs works well for me, so don't be afraid to suggest it).

Thank you all so much for your time!

Comment: If you have `myExponent` correctly, then value/(10^(int)myExponent)` (in psuedo code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some `value` for which the "magnitude" (or power of ten) is `myExponent` we know
[image]

You are rounding this to millions etc, so you should round the exponent

```
lblMoney.Text =  myFragments / (10 ^ Math.Floor(myExponent))
```

(if `myFragments` is the amount we started with)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
Private Sub tmrUnknown_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrUnknown.Tick
    lblMoney.Text = myFragments
    myExponent = Math.Log10(FragmentExponent)

    Select Case True
        Case myExponent < 3
            lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = ""
        Case myExponent < 6
            lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Thousand"
        Case myExponent < 9
            lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Million"
        Case myExponent < 12
            lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Billion"
        Case myExponent < 15
            lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Trillion"
        Case myExponent < 18
            lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Quadrillion"
        Case Else
            lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "Too Damn Much"
    End Select

    If Not lblMoneyMagnitude.Text = "" Then
        lblMoney.Text = Int(myMoney / 10 ^ myExponent).ToString
    End If
End Sub
```